# How to develop OSX application using Visual studio for Mac preview

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.mac

I have .Net Winform project(c#) working in windows.Now,i want to do same project, to work as OSX App in Mac. As per my understanding Microsoft recently launched Visual studio for Mac preview and also it support OSX app development using Xamarin.Mac and also it support .Netcore .

Instead of creating Osx app from scratch,i need to reuse the code which is available in .net winform project.

can i develop UI application using .netcore project? I think .netframework and .netcore more or less same.can i port .netframework to .netcore project and create osx app ?
or

can i use xamarin.mac and reuse the .netframework c# code to create osx app?

I am new to this,so kindly suggest the best way to create OSX app using Visual studio for Mac preview. (Basically i need Tabel view,form controls and graph(there i use zedgraph).Is these view are available here.

Comment: You can use .net-core but that's not winforms. Xamarin is different to winforms so you will have to rewrite. Xamarin.Forms may be all you need.

Comment: Thanks Boggin. I cannot create UI application using .Netcore but i can create UI application using xamarin.forms and xamarin.mac.am i right?

Comment: No. Xamarin.forms does NOT support mac at the moment (only ios/android/windows)

You can use Xamarin.Mac you would create a Mac UI (with c# but using macos api's)

Comment: can i use both both .netframework api's and cococa api's in xamarin.mac project

Comment: You can use .NET BCL API in Xamarin.Mac. Why not create a project and try?

Comment: Forms for XM is coming as a preview scheduled in Q2 this year - https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85747/xamarin-forms-feature-roadmap/p1

Answer (score 1):

In general, the "standard" way of developing cross platform applications is to separate as much of your logic as possible into shared libraries of some type and create "thin" UIs specific to each platform.

Depending on your need, you could easily make that shared code netstandard/PCL/etc compatible and share between platforms or just recompile the project in each solution.

NSTableView will likely solve your needs, but expect it to be significantly more primitive that what you are used to on Windows. Graph controls don't come built in, so you'll need to find a vendor that ships Cocoa controls or draw them yourself.

Here is the quickstart [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/hello,_mac/).

Xamarin.Forms support for macOS is coming in the future, currently [earmarked for Q2 this year](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85747/xamarin-forms-feature-roadmap/p1).